# CSS: Getting a placeholder image take the entire size of the DIV without distortion

Tags: css

I want to place a png as a background image for a div that acts as a placeholder:
https://jsbin.com/hohegiyazu/edit?html,css,output

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }

            .placeholder {
                background-image:url(/images/placeholder.png);
                background-size:100% 100%;
                height:50px;
                flex:1;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I get this effect:
[image: svg example]

The image is distorted according to the width of the element and the left and right margins are not equal.

I want to achieve this effect:
[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you post your html/css so we can provide a good solution

Comment: I did not phrase the question properly. It has been corrected. The SVG tag was removed and HTML code added. If you see that it is right, please  reconsider the down votes and closing recommendations.

Comment: Why not just us a background color?...I'm really unclear on what this asking for.

Comment: I would like to avoid using an inner div with borderRadius and backgroundColor as I want to keep the gray divs flat (without extra inner elements).
So the question is not how to achieve this visual but rather how to place a background image within a single DIV element without know the size of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to change your `background-size` property to `cover`

```
.item {
   background-size: cover;
}
```

It will make sure the image cover the full background, without stretch, though this still depends a lot on how the image actually looks like <strike>as well as how the element using it is set up</strike>.

---

***Update after question edit***

With positioning, i.e. `center center`, you can control what part of the image is of more value and have it centered or left aligned or ...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.placeholder {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height:50px;
  flex:1;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

***Update after 2:nd question edit***

You can use a pseudo element, no extra markup, with background color and rounded corners. This will save you the extra http request, load the page faster (which is really recommended) and you can easily change color and border.

*And you can use an image if you really need one*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
  flex:1;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: red;
}
.placeholder::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 14px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: lightgray;
  /* with image
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300) center center / cover;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder">Hey, there</div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was the ::before hides everything under it. Solved it with border image: https://jsbin.com/segalenufi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Guy The _hiding_ is an easy fix ... updated my answer ... and without the need of an image it will load faster and save you an extra http request, which is really recommended in this case.

Comment: I see. However, it also requires margin which with the border-image I can avoid.

Comment: @Guy That is a visual illusion, the border _is_ a margin in its own way, and you should not use an image when not needed ... also `border-image` has less browser support ... here is a fiddle using border instead of margin: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/eojyx6ck/

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that your PNG seem to include the white margins. So when you stretch it horizontally, the margins are proportionally stretched too and therefore become bigger.

I think you should use the `border-image` property as described here: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

That way, you will be able to define which part of your image can be stretched and which part remains the same width/height, allowing you to keep corners and margins as you want them.